# Log file in EBS R12.2.6 which gives system.out.println statements in side .java files

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-ebs

can someone help me with the name of the log file and location in EBS R12.2.6 , where the statements inside println statments of JAVA is getting logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log path is

> $FMW_HOME/user_projects/domains/EBS_domain_{sid}/servers/oacore_server1/logs

File I was looking for is **"oacore_server1.out"**